# Bootstrap progress bar is not updated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I need to process a filter on a huge amount of JSON data (currently 1.5 MB and growing). The code to filter the data is written and working, but due to the time the filtering takes, I want to display a progress-bar.

I decided to use a Bootstrap progress bar and update it's current value during my loop. I tried with following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%" id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#bar").css("width", percentage + "%").attr("aria-valuenow",percentage);
```

This works fine - as long as I'm stepping it through in a debugger like developer-tools in chrome. Loading the page / running the code without a break-point / debugger results in a not updated progress-bar. Current progress won't be rendered in browser.
I also tried similar solutions with a jqueryUI-progress bar and the HTML5 Tag `<progress>` - but with the same result.

Any suggestions what I did wrong or how to refresh / render DOM after setting a new progress value?

Full loop code:

```
for(var i=0;i<indexes.length;i++) {
    searchterm = "//data[setting = " + indexes[i] + "]";

    for(var j=0;j<jsondata.length;j++){
        current = jsondata[j];
        infoData = {};
        found = JSON.search(current,searchterm);
        if(found.length > 0){
            infoData.licenseNr = current.licenseNr;
            infoData.data = found;
            filteredData.push(infoData);
        }
    }
    percentage = (i+1) * (100/indexes.length);
    $("#bar").css("width", percentage + "%").attr("aria-valuenow",percentage);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem :-(

Comment: please post a fiddle